# Twitter developer signup page seems to be broken with a bug - where to report?

Tags: twitter

Since yesterday I have been trying to sign up on https://dev.twitter.com/resources/signup but strange as it might be, there is a javascript bug and form cannot be submitted.

I have tried Google Chrome, IE, and Mozila Firefox to no avail. In Firefox the following Errors are displayed in console:

[image]

Hard to believe Twitter developer signup page to be broken with a bug. Could someone verify this? And if this happens to be an issue at their end, where should it be reported?

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to Twitter Support, there are several locations in which you can obtain assistance from Twitter.

One of which is the Twitter Support pages: https://support.twitter.com/forms
The best classification for your issue appears to be the Profile section.

Alternatively you can tweet at [@Support](https://twitter.com/support) for assistance as well.